# Access templated "using" in templated parent class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a class hierarchy like this:

```cpp
/* Base templated interface class */
template <class T>
class InterfaceClass {
  public:
    // Normal using sentence
    using InnerType1 = SomeClass<T>;

    // HERE1: Templated using sentence that I want to use in other places
    template<typename SomeType>
    using TplInnerType = SomeOtherClass<InnerType1, SomeType>; 
};

/* Some templated intermediate class inheriting from the interface */
template <typename T>
class Class : InterfaceClass<T> {
  public:
    using BaseType = InterfaceClass<T>;

    // This works
    using typename BaseType::InnerType1;

    // HERE2: This won't work in any form
    using typename BaseType::TplInnerType;
};

/* Then I have some children using the CRTP as: */
class Child1 : Class<Child1> { ... };
class Child2 : Class<Child2> { ... };
```

I would like to use the templated using sentence (HERE1) from InterfaceClass in descendants (HERE2), but I cannot get the compiler (C++11 over clang 10) to resolve the type.
I have tried many combinations following compiler advice, including:

```
  template <typename U> using typename BaseType::TplInnerType<U>;
  template <typename U> using TplInnerType = BaseType::TplInnerType<U>;
  template <typename U> using TplInnerType = typename BaseType::TplInnerType<U>;
  template <typename U> using TplInnerType = BaseType::template TplInnerType<U>;
```

But suggestions drive my in a circle... Is what I try to do even possible?

### Edit - another solution

Apart from @Jarod42 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66154230/1076211), which works for this toy example but not in my real case, I found another solution that works ([sample](https://godbolt.org/z/hsGh6v)):

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Class : InterfaceClass<T> {
  public:
    using BaseType = InterfaceClass<T>;
    using typename BaseType::InnerType1;
    // This works
    template <typename U>
    using TplInnerType = typename BaseType::template TplInnerType<U>;
};
```

Comment: As `Class` already use `T`, you might use other name (as `U`) for template parameter.

Comment: You also miss some public...

Comment: Meta programming is such an ugly thing...

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes and yes. I've changed sample code to reflect those... original code does not suffer from this problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drop `typename`:

```
template <typename T>
class Class : public InterfaceClass<T> {
public:
  using BaseType = InterfaceClass<T>;
  using typename BaseType::InnerType1;
  using BaseType::TplInnerType;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3eYcWs)

Comment: Ok, I am missing something because it does not work in original code. But I can't find what the difference is. For the moment I am accepting this answer, since it really solves the problem as stated in the question. I will come back later to it.